# What are the significant changes between GURPS Lensman 1st and 2nd editions?

Tags: edition-comparison, gurps

What are the significant changes between GURPS Lensman 1st and 2nd editions?

Were there any rules improvements or useful errata or other major reasons to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Are you sure there *was* a second edition? I can find no trace of it in the [SJ Games product list](http://www.sjgames.com/ourgames/everything.html#xG), where GURPS books with multiple editions usually have multiple stock numbers.

Comment: Noble Knight Games lists a 1st and 2nd edition, with slightly different stock numbers. Maybe they made a mistake?

Comment: @JohnDallman Another entry for *GURPS Lenseman (Second Edition)* is [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/rpgitem/48629/gurps-lensman-second-edition). And this is, indeed, a different cover from the one on my shelf. However, so far as I can tell nowhere on the front or back cover images does it say *second edition*.

Comment: Aha! The BoardGameGeek page has a readable image of the back cover, which *does* say "Second Edition", just above the barcode. although with the same stock code as the first edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a thread](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=164396) on the SJ Games forums, discussing the exact same question. The only substantive answer is from Fred Brackin, who has been involved with GURPS playtesting for about as long as it has existed.

> There may have been some fixing of the recursively increasing costs of having ultra-high point Allies like Second-Stage Lensmen.
>
> That's the only thing I can recall being mentioned though.

If you're going to play Lensman nowadays, I'd recommend using the GURPS 4e rule that NPCs don't pay for Allies, to prevent that kind of recursion.